# Adding Custom SignInResults to what's returned from a SignInManager<TUser> PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I want to guarantee that all of my users on sign-in have signed our EULA, and to me, it's similar to the built-in `SignInResult.TwoFactorRequired`, because I'd like to kick them through the EULA signing process before finalizing their sign-in.  Does anyone know of any resources that shows how to create a custom `SignInResult` so that all of the users of my Identity server will have to follow the same rules on sign-in?

I'd implement a custom `SignInManager`, but `PasswordSignInAsync` still returns a concrete `SignInResult` and I'm not sure if it's possible to wedge in my additional desired states there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're not going to be able to just override `PasswordSignInAsync`, but you could create a new method that returns your custom result class and simply hands off the actual sign-in part to `PasswordSignInAsync`.

However, by the time you get done create derived types, with custom methods and states, and bootstrap everything, it probably is just simpler and more straight-forward to just read the value from the user after sign in, and react accordingly. For example, you can (and probably should) set the EULA acceptance as a claim on the user. Then, you can just do something like:

```
// sign in user

if (User.FindFirstValue("eula") == null)
{
    return Redirect("/eula");
}
```

Even better, you can create a custom action filter that checks if the user is authenticated, and if so, whether they have the claim. If not, then you redirect to your EULA acceptance page. Then that action filter can be made global in `Startup.cs` and you don't even need to think about it anymore.

Comment: I sorta wish I could do something more magical, and inline with the existing sign-in infrastructure, but I think your suggestion of the filter is what I'm going to go with.  Thanks.