# How to add a custom SignInResults that halts the signin until an action is completed in SignInManager<TUser>

Tags: asp.net-core-identity, duende-identity-server

I'm trying to include a step for terms of use accepting during the login process in Identity Server, much like this question [Adding Custom SignInResults to what's returned from a SignInManager<TUser> PasswordSignInAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640053/adding-custom-signinresults-to-whats-returned-from-a-signinmanagertuser-passw).

The problem is that the answer provided there is unsatisfactory because the screen we redirect to can be skipped as the user is already signed in.
Is there a solution where the whole sign in process is halted until an action is completed (similar to TFA flow)?

I think overriding the SingInManager class and implementing my own logic could be dangerous as I wouldn't be calling the base method anymore and thus would not benefit from updates down the road.